# Pass value from child to parent

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have a component in Nuxt UI.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <label for="phone" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">{{
      $t('nav.cellphone')
    }}</label>
    <div class="relative mb-6" dir="ltr">
      <UInput
        v-model="phone"
        class="text-left"
        :placeholder="$t('registration.cellphone')"
        icon="i-heroicons-phone"
        type="phone"
        name="phone"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The parent is :

```html
<LazyModalsLoginsignupElementsPhone />
```

The question is I would like to have the current and change value of UInput in parent in `<script setup>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html) to bind a parent ref to the child. The child accepts the v-model as a prop, and emits the value back to the parent whenever it changes.

**Parent.vue**

```html
<template>
   <child v-model="phone" />
</template>
```

```js
<script setup>
import child from './child.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const phone = ref('test')
</script>
```

**Child.vue**

```
<template>
  <UContainer class="mt-4">
    <UInput
      :value="modelValue"
      @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
      class="text-left"
      :placeholder="$t('registration.cellphone')"
      icon="i-heroicons-phone"
      type="phone"
      name="phone"
    />
  </UContainer>
</template>
```

```
<script setup>
defineProps(['modelValue']);
defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);
</script>
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxtlabs-ui-dfa8zl?file=child.vue,app.vue)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ref attribute in the child component and the onUpdated lifecycle hook in the parent component.

Child Component

```
<template>
  <input
    v-model="phoneValue"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    :type="type"
    :name="name"
  />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, defineProps } from 'vue';

const { modelValue, placeholder, type, name } = defineProps(['modelValue', 'placeholder', 'type', 'name']);
const phoneValue = ref(modelValue);

// Emit the updated value when the phoneValue changes
watch(phoneValue, (newValue) => {
  emit('update:modelValue', newValue);
});
</script>
```

Parent Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label for="phone" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">{{
      $t('nav.cellphone')
    }}</label>
    <div class="relative mb-6" dir="ltr">
      <UInput
        v-model="phone"
        class="text-left"
        :placeholder="$t('registration.cellphone')"
        icon="i-heroicons-phone"
        type="phone"
        name="phone"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
import UInput from './UInput.vue'; // Import the child component

const phone = ref('');

// Watch for changes in the phone value and do something with it
watch(phone, (newValue) => {
  // Handle the updated value here (e.g., send it to an API, perform validation, etc.)
  console.log('New Phone Value:', newValue);
});
</script>
```

use the ref function to create a reference for the phone value in the parent component. The watch function is used to observe changes to the phone value